# UITextField text not showing on iPhone 6 Plus (device only)

Tags: ios, iphone

We have an app with a UITextField based search field. It works fine on all devices except on iPhone 6 Plus hardware devices, where the text is not visible. It is, however, visible on the iPhone 6 Plus simulator.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Have you used IB and constraints?

Comment: All valid questions, I will get back soon with more details.